# Why Wingdings 2 is not interpreted in rdlc reportviewers but in pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using Wingdings 2 in rdlc report and when I export it to pdf, it works but when displaying in browser, it doesn't work at all. Why?

in expression field it's like

```
=IIF(Fields!Testname.Value, Chr(82), Chr(163))
```

but in web browser it appears like

```
RTestname


£FieldName
```

See the special character?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ChrW(&H2611), ChrW(&H2610)` and setting font family to `Arial Unicode MS` helped.

```
=IIF(Fields!Columnname.Value,ChrW(&H2611), ChrW(&H2610))
```